# how to add another loop based on the id of the first loop, in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to display the data of all employees based on places, where data places are looped based on date data, here is the code.

in the model

```
public function getSchedule()
    {
        $builder = $this->db->table('tb_dates');
        ....
        $dates = $builder->get()->getResultArray();

        foreach ($dates as $key => $value) {
            $builder = $this->db->table('tb_places');

            $builder->join('tb_dates', 'tb_dates.iddate = tb_places.iddate');
            $builder->where('tb_dates.iddate', $value['iddate']);
            $result = $builder->get();
            $places = $dates[$key]['places'] = $result->getResultArray();

            // more looping (this question)
            foreach ($places as $key => $value) {
               ....
            }
        }
        return $dates;
    }
```

and then in controller :

```
$data['sch'] = json_encode($this->schedule->getSchedule());
return view('admin/index', $data);
```

in view :

```
<?php $schedules = json_decode($sch); ?>
<?php foreach ($schedules as $schedule) : ?>

    ....

        <?php foreach ($schedule->places as $key) : ?>

             ....
             
                 **for example, i want an loop for the employee data in here**
                     .......

        <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: for the employee loop section, I've tried that, using the same query as the id query for places, i.e. looping back based on the place id, but it got an error.